# angularjs FormGroup valid is true but return false

Tags: javascript, angular

angularjs FormGroup valid is true but return false

```js
 this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
      'phone': new FormControl(this.loginer.phone, [
        Validators.required,
        validateMobile
      ]),
      'password': new FormControl(this.loginer.password,[
        Validators.required
      ]),
  })
  public formChange(){
    console.log(this.loginForm);
    console.log(this.loginForm.valid);
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It means that state of your form has been changed after `FormChange` method was called. `console.log` shows you the current state of the object, not the object at the snapshot in time of when it was called.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    loginForm: FormGroup;
    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            phone: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
            password: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
        })
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.loginForm);
        console.log(this.loginForm.valid);
    }
}
```

[image: Valid empty method]